RigidBody2D bounces back on collision how to fix it
When player enter the collision with other game object it bounces back which generate shaking if player just moves in this object.
I already tried physics material with no bounciness also i tried angular drag and changing mass.
public void playerMovement(float horizontal, float vertical)
{
    if (!canMove) return; // Skip movement if movement is disabled

    Vector3 viewPos = transform.position;
    viewPos += new Vector3(horizontal, vertical, 0).normalized * StatsManager.CmoveSpeed * Time.deltaTime;

    // Locking the player movement within the screen bounds horizontally
    viewPos.x = Mathf.Clamp(viewPos.x, screenBounds.x * -1 + objectWidth, screenBounds.x - objectWidth);

    // Wrap around logic for top and bottom
    if (viewPos.y > screenBounds.y + objectHeight)
    {
        viewPos.y = screenBounds.y * -1 - objectHeight;
    }
    else if (viewPos.y < screenBounds.y * -1 - objectHeight)
    {
        viewPos.y = screenBounds.y + objectHeight;
    }

    transform.position = viewPos;
}


Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You haven't provided a lot of details but this is sounds like a common issue. This tutorial explains the problem (if this is your issue). You must move the Rigid Body and not the game object itself in order to let the physics system handle the movement. Hope it helps.
